# MongoDB get all items and mark favorites

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to get all items and mark those in my favorites list as favorites.

Supose I have this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "favorites": [2]
    }
}
```

and this:

```
{
    "item": {
        "_id"= "1",
        "value": "myval"
    }
}

{
    "item": {
        "_id"= "2",
        "value": "myval"
    }
}

...  // Rest of documents
```

I want to get this

```
{
    "item": {
        "_id"= "1",
        "value": "myval"
    }
}

{
    "item": {
        "_id"= "2",
        "value": "myval",
        "isFavorite": "yes"  // I just want to mark my favorites somehow.
    }
}

... // Rest of documents
```

How would I achieve this in MongoDB?

Comment: Your JSON/BSON syntax is a bit off, but there's no way in mongoDB to do that automatically. You're going to need to write some code to take the list from the one user document and update each item individually. It's a few lines of code in most drivers you'd need to write.

Answer (score 0):

Given a user with an array of favorites where each entry is the item id - for example:
    {
        _id: 112233
        "user": {
            "favorites": [2,7,13]
        }
    }

You would have gotten the favorites array [2,7,13]

Then compose the update to your **items** collection (presuming you have a user id 112233)

```
>db.items.update({"_id": {$in:[2,7,13]}}, {$set:{"isFavorite":true}},{ multi: true })
// yeilding
> db.items.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 2, "isFavorite" : true, "value" : "myVal" }
```

In your example, your items were somewhat nested - not sure if this is for real.

If your item record is

```
{ _id:999,item:{_id:1,value:"myValue"}}
```

and you really meant to update the items who's "item._id" is 1 (rather than the document mandatory _id 999) then you would

```
db.items.update({"item._id": {$in:[2,7,13]}}, {$set:{"item.isFavorite":true}},{ multi: true })
```

As noted by @WiredPrairie though, it is a peculiar document structure.
One might expect users to have their _id as a first class field - every record has one.

Presuming that your items collection contains items shared by all, you would probably not want to store "isFavorite" on an item since it's not everyone's favorite. Another way to model that is to add to each item an array containing the ids of users who fav'd them.

Something like

```
>db.items.update({"_id": {$in:[2,7,13]}},{$addToSet:{"favoredByUserIds": "user1"}},{ multi: true })
// yeilding 'user1' in the favored by array
> db.items.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : "myVal" }
{ "_id" : 2, "favoredByUserIds" : [ "user1" ], "value" : "myVal" }
```

Using $addToSet ensures the operation can be repeated, but "user1" will only be added once.